# Using Automator, Applescript & FFMPEG with If/Else Statements

Tags: applescript, audio, automator

I'm just not finding the resources I need.  Perhaps someone can point me in the right direction and delete this post afterward. I'm working on making an Applet that is more complex than the one I have now.  Right now I have audio files as inputs to 1 of 2 applets.  I want to combine these into one eventually with if and else if, then operators.  But first I need to be able to extract sample rate and bit depth information from the audio file.

I'm fine using ffprobe or mediainfo - I think ffprobe might be the easier way to go but I'm having trouble finding:

1) How to use ffprobe as a shell within an applescript to extract the sample rate and bit depth

2) how to use the return of those commands do drive if/then or else if commands to run 1 or more ffmpeg scripts.

I would even be happy to use applescript and "properties of the_file" if it can be extracted.  I imagine it can since info on a mac usually shows the sample rate and bit depth.

The script I'm using so far looks like this:

```
on remove_extension(this_name)
    if this_name contains "." then
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
        set x to the offset of "." in this_name
        set this_name to (text (x + 1) thru -1 of this_name)
        set this_name to (the reverse of every character of this_name) as string
    end if
    return this_name
end remove_extension

on run {input, parameters}
    repeat with file_ in input
        tell application "System Events"
            set inputFilename to name of (get properties of file_)
        end tell
        set inputFilePath to quoted form of (POSIX path of file_)
        set outputFilePath to quoted form of (my remove_extension(POSIX path of file_) & ".wav")
        tell application "Terminal"
            activate
            do script "/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i " & inputFilePath & " -c:a copy -rf64 auto -write_bext 1 -metadata originator='Church History Department' -metadata originator_reference='" & inputFilename & "' " & outputFilePath
        end tell
    end repeat
    return input
end run
```

This takes a file and rewraps it adding metadata and saving the resulting file in the same folder as the original.  The other script does mostly the same but re encodes the file and adds the metadata, saving the result to the same folder as the original.

I really want to be able to say, extract sample rate and bit depth and if they are >= then execute this ffmpeg script else if <= then execute a different ffmpeg script.

Thanks in advance!